# PHP echo all table rows by 'Key' => 'Value' columns - Experience

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, array-push

trying write script that **echo all table row's columns info ,'Key' => 'Value' pairs**

**i tried do following steps:**
**1.** get all columns Fields
**2.** run SELECT query
**3.** echo JSON value Key as (table Fields count)

```
$table_name = 'Users';
$fieldname=array(); 
$fieldnames=array();
$fieldnames_C; //fieldNames count


//--------------------------------------------- get colums 'key' array + count;
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM {$table_name}");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

           $fieldname = $row['Field']; 
           array_push($fieldnames, $fieldname);    //ARRAY ADD OBJECT       
       }       

    $fieldnames_C =  count($fieldnames);
    echo($fieldnames_C); 
}


    $users = array();
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table_name}");                
//for table count
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {                   
//for columns count  
            $i = 0;
            while($i < $fieldnames_C)
            {                   
            $fieldname = $fieldnames[$i];           


             $users[] = array(     

            $fieldname => $row[$fieldname]

            );

            $i++;
            }



          array_push($users, $fieldname => $row[$fieldname]);

        }


          echo json_encode(array('response' => $users));                
          mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

**Output goes like this:**

```
[{"PID":"79"},{"UserID":"ofir"},{"UserName":"ofir name"},{"UserLat":"32.0511"},{"UserLon":"34.8029"}]
```

**trying Output like this:**
simple JsonArray as Table SELECT count;

```
[{"PID":"79","UserID":"ofir","UserName":"ofir name","UserLat":"32.0511","UserLon":"34.8029"]
```

thanks for answering!

Comment: how is this not working for you?

Comment: it insert every columns field key+value into array;
i'm trying insert into array all table row into array

Comment: Try `$users[] = array($fieldname => $row[$fieldname]);`. PHP recommends using `[]` to add a value to an array if you are doing one at a time, since it avoids overhead of a function..this should also fix your problem.

Comment: sam, what you wrote already coded
it will insert every pair key value into index array.
what i'm trying to insert into array all row's columns key =>value pairs

Answer (score 2):

Your code could be drastically simplified:

```
$data = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table_name}");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $data[] = $row;
}
$field_names = array_keys($data[0]);
```

Of course, this will only work properly if your query actually returns any results, but assuming it does, this is literally all you need to replicate what you're doing.

Comment: hi Marc
your above code echo's the column's key and index,
**i'm trying echo column's key and current row value**

Marc code: 

`( [0] => PID [1] => UserID [2] => UserName [3] => UserPass [4] => UserLat [5] => UserLon [6] => Available [7] => Status [8] => UserKind [9] => deviceToken )`

i'm trying echo column's key and current row value